# Where did tree spiking prevent the most logging?

Tags: crime, forestry

Old growth trees can be [very valuable](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/how-thousand-year-old-trees-became-new-ivory-180963365/) as lumber. [Tree spiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_spiking), a form of [ecotage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecotage) or [monkeywrenching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_Wrench_Gang), is driving a metal or ceramic rod into a living tree. This discourages logging by marking trees or stands as dangerous to cut and mill.

[image: Spiked tree warning]

Although it is sometimes [possible to remove the spikes](https://books.google.com/books?id=mnh1vnILhb8C&lpg=PA34&ots=b3n_jULylq&dq=spiked%20tree%20removed&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false), spiking has deterred logging: ["prudence directs that in most cases spiked trees be left alone"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zs9mDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT76&ots=YU_YwXuaVn&dq=trees%20spiked%20prevented&pg=PT78#v=onepage&q&f=false). For example, in 1982, some 2000 trees at the Grouse Mountain Ski Resort in North Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada were [reportedly not logged](https://www.judibari.info/sources/Lawhorn/DebatewithWatson) after being spiked.

In terms of the number of trees left standing, what was the largest single logging project derailed by spiking?

Comment: Why are there 2 VTC ? The question seems legit to me, even if I am unsure to which SE it belongs.

Comment: As a general observation, a question which finds it necessary to create *three new tags* is probably about a topic we have not previously considered history (or we would have the tags in place).

Comment: The question is also about a topic some might view differently, considering that even the leader of Earth-first has [renounced tree spiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_spiking#United_States), and it is a felony in the US, it might be considered by some more [eco-terrorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eco-terrorism) than a valid form of environmentalism.

Comment: @justCal It does match "eco-terrorism" since it is a non-violent tactics and its point has never been to hurt anyone, most often trees were marked to prevent chainsaws from causing accidents. The fact that it is a tactic from the past is an argument for keeping the question on H.SE.

Comment: Just bringing up a possible reason this question might attract negative attention. (eco-terrorism is mentioned on the OPs linked wiki page)

Comment: @Evargalo logging is *the* profession with the highest on-job mortality rate.  seems to me embedding large pieces of metal with the full knowledge and intent that they may be hit with high-powered machinery wielded by a human at close proximity is precisely the definition of terrorism and lack of consideration for human life.  and this  as a person who really gets annoyed by the use of the word *terrorism* in all sorts of non-terrorist contexts.  and someone who supports protecting old growth forests.

Comment: That the answer is primary research citing archival material indicates the question is a poor match for history.se: historians haven't historicised it.  Technique focused questions are poor matches, historians tend to work questions around class war in Virginian forestry; or Occupational Health and Safety as disciplinary conducts.  This question also strongly resembles past attempts to smuggle questions on technical efficiency in by gesturing at the past.  Things in the past don't make it history.

Comment: To be honest, given the current debates about tagging in [meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/), I'm really not sure it's a great idea to create multiple new tags without first asking the community view on whether those tags are needed in meta.

Comment: @AaronBrick The current discussions happening on meta suggests the community feels otherwise.  See [here](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4076/24858) and [here](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4073/24858) for example.  If you have a different view, by all means feel free to contribute to that debate on meta.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Thanks for providing the links. I was not aware of the ongoing discussion in meta, and have just posted my views there.

Answer (score 11):

> **Question:**
>   Where did tree spiking prevent the most logging?

**Short Answer:**
Tree Spiking was most effective in Virginia's George Washington National Forest, and in the Wanatchee Forest's Icicle River drainage in Washington state, or where Logging wasn't a major part of the local economy.   These are the only two places where tree spiking actually interrupted for a time lumber sales.  Where logging was a major factor in the local economy tree spiking proved to be ineffective deterent to logging after it's initial introduction.

> **[The Secret History of Tree Spiking](https://archive.iww.org/history/library/Bari/TreeSpiking2/)**
>   Even unabashed Earth First! apologist Chris Manes, writing in his well researched book Green Rage, could only come up with two timber sales that were canceled because they were spiked, one in George Washington National Forest in Virginia, and one in the Wanatchee Forest's Icicle River drainage in Washington state. I don't know about the trees in Virginia, but the Icicle River sale has since been cut.

**Detailed Answer:**
Tree spiking which is believed to have originated in the United States in the early 1980's spread out to several countries, including Canada, and New Zealand.   While initially it caused some casualties,

> **[Tree Spiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_spiking#:~:text=It%20is%20believed%20that%20tree,in%20the%20late%2019th%20century)**
>   In 1987, California mill worker George Alexander was seriously injured when the bandsaw he was operating hit an 11-inch spike embedded in a 12-inch trunk with a worn-out blade he had earlier requested to be replaced.

It was ineffective because once allerted the the problem it was easy enough for the lumber industry or Forest Service to dispatch workers with metal detectors to remove spikes from the trees.  Even when spikes have been missed the lumber industry ultimately chalks it up to the cost of doing business.

> **[The Secret History of Tree Spiking](https://archive.iww.org/history/library/Bari/TreeSpiking2/)**
>   there have been scores and scores of tree-spikings, and in the vast majority of cases, the Forest Service or timber company just sent people in with metal detectors and, often with great public fanfare, removed the spikes and cut the trees. Sometimes spikes were missed and sometimes they hit the blades in sawmills. But the timber industry has made it quite clear that this is a price they are willing to pay.

### Comments

> **from AaronBrick,**  Do mills simply expect to put their employees in danger and break their saw blades by cutting through ceramic spikes that their metal detectors could not locate?

This Dec 2019 **[Newspaper Article](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/12/27/the-10-most-dangerous-jobs-in-america-according-to-bls-data.html)** quotes the United States Bureau of Labor Statistics listing Logging as the most dangerous job in the United States.   Sites fatalities coming from loggers being struck by flying debree and equipment failure.  So I would say.. pretty much yes,  Logging is a dangerous job and Mills put their employees at risk.   Found statistics from other years where Logging was top 2 for other years too.  It's not only spikes which cause saw blades/chains to break.  dense wood(knots)  or the weight of the wood can also pinch the blade and cause it break.  The net result is the same.  loggers can be put in danger when their equipment breaks.

**Sources:**

- **[Tree Spiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_spiking#:~:text=It%20is%20believed%20that%20tree,in%20the%20late%2019th%20century)**
- **[The Secret History of Tree Spiking](https://archive.iww.org/history/library/Bari/TreeSpiking2/)**

Comment: Do mills simply expect to put their employees in danger and break their saw blades by cutting through ceramic spikes that their metal detectors could not locate?

Comment: @AaronBrick Just look at the numbers in a story [here](https://archive.seattletimes.com/archive/?date=19921226&slug=1532061). $20,000 cost in down time and equipment vs a $4.57 ***million dollar investment*** into the lumber. The damage was less then a half of one percent of the investment. Not important to the corporation doing the work, just to any workers endangered by the actions.

Comment: @AaronBrick,  responded at the end of my answer

Comment: @justCal That accounting is a very helpful way to frame the decision.